# Counting while using recursion with strings from inputs

Tags: python, string, recursion, counting

I'm trying to create a game where the score is dependent on what the letters are worth. I'm having trouble with keeping a count on the side while still recursing to the next letter of the string. I'm really stuck & I hope you can help!

```
def net_zero():
    guess_prompt = input('Guess a string: ')
    win_display = 'Congratulations you win'
    low_vowels = "aeiou" # +1
    low_constants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz" # -1
    up_vowels = "AEIOU" # +2
    up_constants = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ" # -2
    ten_digits = "0123456789" # +3
    #else -3

    count = 0
    if len(guess_prompt) == 0:
        return count
    elif guess_prompt[0] in low_vowels:
        return (count + 1) + guess_prompt[1:]
    elif guess_prompt[0] in low_constants:
        return (count - 1) + guess_prompt[1:]
    elif guess_prompt[0] in up_vowels:
        return (count + 2) + guess_prompt[1:]
    elif guess_prompt[0] in up_constants:
        return (count - 2) + guess_prompt[1:]
    elif guess_prompt[0] in ten_digits:
        return (count + 3) + guess_prompt[1:] 
    else: return (count - 3) + guess_prompt[1:]
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Maybe I've been awake for too long but I don't see any recursion or looping of some sort.

Comment: Maybe by "recursion" you mean "slicing".  Also, your are trying to add an integer to a string, which will give an error.

Comment: And by looping you mean "nested `if`"?

Comment: Think he genuinely wanted to iterate and collect score depending on letter type

Comment: @Noah Trotman What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

I think you would like to do following

```
count = 0

if len(guess_prompt) == 0:
        return count
for letter in guess_prompt:
    if letter in low_vowels:
        count +=1
    if letter in low_constants:
        count -=1
    ...

return count
```

Comment: `if letter in lower_consonants: count -= 1`

Answer (score 0):

I feel you can use dict instead of using string content for lookup. It will improve lookup time.

```
guess_prompt = "aaB4??BBBBB"
value = {}
for char in "aeiou":
  value[char] = 1

for char in "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz":
  value[char] = -1

for char in "AEIOU":
  value[char] = 2

for char in "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ":
  value[char] = -2

for char in "0123456789":
  value[char] = 3

count = 0
for char in guess_prompt:
  count = count + value.get(char, -3) #default value -3

print(count) ## PRINTS -13 ##
```